# React Typescript: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'PropsInterface'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-v4

I am trying to redirect if a call to the database fails by using `props.history.push('/');` but i get the error `Property 'history' does not exist on type 'PropsInterface'` to confuse things further I am already passing in props from the parent and have them defined in `PropsInterface` how can I extend this interface to allow history

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { RouteProps } from 'react-router';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Global } from '../globalState';
import { Dispatch, SET_SHARED } from '../globalState';


interface PropsInterface {
  location: RouteProps['location'];
  children: RouteProps['children'];
}

const Layout: React.FC<PropsInterface> = (props: PropsInterface) => {
  const { global } = useContext(Global);
  const { dispatch } = useContext(Dispatch);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi = async (path: string) => {
...
        if (response.status === 200) {
          localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', content.jwtToken);
          dispatch({ type: SET_SHARED, value: content.shared });
        } else {
          localStorage.clear();
          props.history.push('/');
//                ^
//                 Property 'history' does not exist on type 'PropsInterface'.ts(2339)
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

Here `PropsInterface` doesn't have access to history. So to get hold of history you need to use `RouteComponentProps` which is provided with withRoutes()

Modify your code like below:

```
interface PropsInterface extends RouteComponentProps<any> {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Sam thanks for this, where do I put this snippet? please, could you expand your answer a little to show where it goes?

Comment: @Bill where you define that interface? Your "question" seems to be more of a tutorial request....it's not even clear *why* you're defining an interface since you're not adding any custom props...

Comment: @sam You *probably* should pass something other than any as the type parameter, but still that solves the problem. Nice first answer!

Comment: The error i get is `Interface 'PropsInterface' incorrectly extends interface 'RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>'.
  Types of property 'location' are incompatible.
    Type 'Location<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Location<any>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Location<any>'.ts(2430)`